# How can I get an interpolated value from a Pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, interpolation

I have a simple Pandas data frame with two columns, 'Angle' and 'rff'. I want to get an interpolated 'rff' value based on entering an Angle that falls between two Angle values (i.e. between two index values) in the data frame.  For example, I'd like to enter 3.4 for the Angle and then get an interpolated 'rff'.   What would be the best way to accomplish that?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1.0,45.0], [2,56], [3,58], [4,62],[5,70]]   #Sample data
s= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Angle', 'rff'])    
print(s)
s = s.set_index('Angle')                             #Set 'Angle' as index
print(s)
result = s.at[3.0, "rff"]                            
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.interp(3.4, s.index, s.rff)
#59.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
data = [[1.0,45.0], [2,56], [3,58], [4,62],[5,70]]   #Sample data
s= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Angle', 'rff'])    
print(s)

print(np.interp(3.4, s.Angle, s.rff))

>>> 59.6
```